# PHP Annotation Library

Tags: php, annotations

Which is the best PHP Annotation library out there?

Thanks

Comment: *(related)* http://wiki.php.net/rfc/annotations

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[PHP Addendum](https://github.com/jsuchal/addendum)

One of the best...