# Can I disable some errors that match a specific criteria on a PHP script in PhpStorm 8.0.2?

Tags: php, phpstorm, php-parse-error

I would like to ask e.g. if I have a code like this:

```
/**
 * Doc comment
 */
@Annotation
class MyClass {

}
```

I know it will generate a parse error cause PHP doesn't have annotations natively like Java (i.e. outside of comments), but anyway is there a way to make PhpStorm not to complain about it?

[image]

Can I disable anyhow that `Expected: semicolon` in PhpStorm? I mean something like disabling error checking for a pattern matching `@[a-zA-Z]+` or something like that?

EDIT: @notulysses The Inspection window shows only `Typo` and `Warning`, how can I see the `Error`s too?

[image]

Comment: [Look at this](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/suppressing-inspections.html)

Comment: What purpose does that serve? Genuinely curious.

Comment: @notulysses I have already looked at the link you linked me, the problem is that PhpStorm shows me only `Typo` (green inspection) and `Warning` (yellow inspection) but that `Expected semicolon` refers to an `Error` (a red inspection, I guess), and it is not shown in the *Inspection* window (please, check the picture in my edit). Can I also disable error inspections? If so, how?

Comment: @castis Found this answer SO quite interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623499/how-is-annotation-useful-in-php#answer-23415342

Comment: @castis If I paste that code in the answer linked above in the IDE editor everything after `__halt_compiler();` is not parsed by the IDE and I don't get any error, but I would like to separate those files and have that `AnnotationExample` class in a separate file, and edit it with the IDE, though with the `@cache` annotation or any other annotation maintaned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot -- those errors come from Lexer/Parser which is a lower level than inspections (which you may suppress/disable completely on individual basis) and therefore is not suppressible (unless, you write your own PHP-alike language support plugin).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Anyway, just to know how to do it, with `which you may suppress/disable completely on individual basis` you mean that they can still be suppressed/disable e.g. per-project? How can I do it?

Comment: How to do what? Disable inspections? Inspections are already project-specific setting .. so you just go to `Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Editor | Inspections` and disable unwanted. You can also disable them not for the whole project , but for specific scope only (e.g. certain folders or files).

Comment: Yes, I know I can disable `Typo` and `Warning` inspections form `Preferences | Editor | Inspections` but actually how can I disable a single `Error` like `Expected: semicolon`? If I search for them in the search field in `Preferences | Editor | Inspections` they doesn't show.

Comment: As I have said in my actual answer: this error you are referring to comes from a Lexer/Parser and is NOT suppressible AT ALL. Only inspections (which is a higher/additional/optional level) can be suppressed.

Comment: Aaah, all right, I didn't get it through and through! Thanks!